# Listview help..(Windows Forms)

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

How can I check if no items "At all" selected from listview?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if( myListView.SelectedItems == null || myListView.SelectedItems.Count == 0 )
{
}
```

See [ListView..::.SelectedItems Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.selecteditems.aspx) for more info.

EDIT: As per the MSDN documentation:

> If no items are currently selected, an
>   empty
>   ListView..::.SelectedListViewItemCollection
>   is returned.

So the null check is not needed in this case and you can simply do:

```
if( myListView.SelectedItems.Count == 0 )
{
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you have to check for null?

Comment: I think testing for null should not be necessary. Would be really ugly then.

Comment: msdn: "If no items are currently selected, an empty ListView.SelectedListViewItemCollection is returned."

Comment: @tanascius I wasn't sure off the top of my head, so I left the null check in. You're correct though, and I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Just remember that if the `ListView` is in virtual mode, you cannot access the `SelectedItems` collection. It's better to always use the `SelectedIndicies` collection, since that is always available.